# Routing from one component to another in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My app is structured into the following components.

```
<App>
  <Header/>
  <Content/>
  <Footer/>
</App
```

This is my App Component,

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Header/>
                <Content/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

This is the Header,

```
const Header = () => (
    <header className="homepage-header">
        <div className="container containerLogo">
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo"/>
        </div>
        <div className="container containerNav">
            <ul>
            <li><NavLink to="/"> Overview </NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/how-it-works">How it works</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/plans-and-pricing">Plans & Pricing</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="container containerButton">
            <button className="signInButton">Sign In</button>
            <button className="signUpButton">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

    </header>
);
```

And this is my Content,

```
const Content = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/about"><Home/></Route>
        <Route path="/how-it-works"><Works/></Route>
        <Route path="/plans-and-pricing"><Plans/></Route>
    </Switch>

);
```

This isn't working - the none of the components are being rendered.
How do I route to different components inside `Content` from the `Header`?

I understand how routing works and will be using client side routing. The links to different pages are anchor tags here because I'm not sure what component to wrap in `BrowserRouter`.
I'm new to React, thus the question.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start - the code at the top has almost the same use case example, if you don't understand any part of it, let me know

Comment: @tachko I'm not sure if you understood my requirement. My Router is inside a Header and it routes different components inside a Content component. The example you provided demonstrates nothing like that. The components are rendered inside the same component the router is in.

Comment: Do you use ```react-router-dom```?

Comment: @MartialAnouman yes I'm using `react-router-dom`

Comment: if you are using react-router-dom then where is it in your code? You haven't set up the main routes at all. These people are giving you good advice. Read the docs for react-router-dom.

Comment: You need to set up your routes where the Header, Content, and Footer are being rendered. Scrap content and replace it with your routes. Keep Header and footer outside of the routes so they persist on url change, then you can use Link from react-router-dom to change routes from the Header.

Comment: @GrantSingleton I've updated the question, still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try to add ‘exact’ prop to tour route

Comment: It looks like you  don't have any component that renders at the root level i.e. `exact path = "/"`. Can you temporarily set the above path on the Home component.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to wrap all your application inside `BrowserRouter`. Look at the following structure:

**Routes Component**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

export const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        {// Part of your app which never change}
        <Header/>
        {// Part of your app which change with routing}
        <Switch>
            <Route path='...' component={/* Component to reach with this route */} />
        </Switch>
        {// Part of your app which never change}
        <Footer/>
    </Router>
)
```

**App component**

```
// import Routes component
const App = () => (<Routes />)
```

The routing part is between the `Switch` component, so this is the place to setup your navigation. Even if the `Header` and `Footer` component don't change, they will probably hold link to trigger navigation. They must be inside `Router` component.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Your Switch is outside the `Header`. I was specific in my question that I'll be routing from inside the `Header` and the components need to render inside `Content`.

Comment: What do you mean by « routing inside the header  »?

Comment: @root I believe the Switch component only needs to wrap the Route components. You can also avoid using Switch all together. The BrowserRouting is the component that needs to wrap the Header and Content which it looks like you've already done.